# shellcode calls different syscall while runing alone as individiual code and while running with C++ code

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, nasm, system-calls

I've such a code that run's shell:

```
BITS 64

global _start
_start:

  mov rax, 59

  jmp short file
  c1:
  pop rdi

  jmp short argv
  c2:
  pop rsi

  mov rdx, 0

  syscall

file:

  call c1
  db '/bin/sh',0

argv:

  call c2
  dq arg, 0

arg:

  db 'sh',0
```

It works when it's built in this way:

```
nasm -f elf64 shcode.asm
ld shcode.o -o shcode
```

Althougt, when I bring it into binary form with:

```
nasm -f bin shcode.asm
```

paste it into following C++ code:

```
int main(void)
{

  char kod[]="\xB8\x3B\x00\x00\x00\xEB\x0B\x5F\xEB\x15\x5E\xBA\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0F\x05\xE8\xF0\xFF\xFF\xFF\x2F\x62\x69\x6E\x2F\x73\x68\x00\xE8\xE6\xFF\xFF\xFF\x34\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x73\x68\x00";
  reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(kod)();

  return 0;

}
```

make it with clang++ texp.cpp -o texp.e -Wl,-z,execstack and execute, shell isn't running.

After running it with

```
strace ./texp.e
```

I see something like this (I stopped this process with ^C):

```
syscall_0xffffffffffffffda(0x7ffc23e0a297, 0x7ffc23e0a2a4, 0, 0x4a0, 0x7fe1ff3039b0, 0x7fe1ff69b960) = -1 ENOSYS (Nie zaimplementowana funkcja)
syscall_0xffffffffffffffda(0x7ffc23e0a297, 0x7ffc23e0a2a4, 0, 0x4a0, 0x7fe1ff3039b0, 0x7fe1ff69b960) = -1 ENOSYS (Nie zaimplementowana funkcja)
.
.
.
syscall_0xffffffffffffffda(0x7ffc23e0a297, 0x7ffc23e0a2a4, 0, 0x4a0, 0x7fe1ff3039b0, 0x7fe1ff69b960) = -1 ENOSYS (Nie zaimplementowana funkcja)
^Csyscall_0xffffffffffffffda(0x7ffc23e0a297, 0x7ffc23e0a2a4, 0, 0x4a0,  0x7fe1ff3039b0, 0x7fe1ff69b960strace: Process 2806 detached
 <detached ...>
```

Nie zaimplementowana funkcja - Function not implemented

So the program ( aka shellcode ) is propably running improper syscall.

Comment: off-topic: you don't need separate `jmp/call/pop` sequences: once you have one you can do `lea rsi, [rdi + argv - file_data]` to get the other with a 4-byte `lea`.  (put a `file_data` label on the `db` in file: as well as on the `call`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your C++ shellcode caller, `strace` shows your `execve` system call was

```
execve("/bin/sh", [0x34], NULL)         = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

The later `syscall_0xffffffffffffffda(...) = -1 ENOSYS` are from an infinite loop with RAX = `-EFAULT` instead of 59, and then from `RAX=- ENOSYS` (again not a valid call number).  This loop is created by your `call/pop`.

---

Presumably because you hexdumped an absolute address for `arg` from an unlinked `.o` or from a PIE executable, which is how you got `0x34` as the absolute address.

Obviously the whole approach of embedding an absolute address in your shellcode doesn't work if it's going to run from a randomized stack address, with no relocation fixup.  **`dq arg, 0` is not position-independent.**

You need to construct at least the `argv` array yourself (usually with `push`) using pointers.  You could also use a `push imm32` to construct `arg` itself.  e.g. `push 'shsh'` / `lea rax, [rsp+2]`.

Or the most common trick is to take advantage of a Linux-specific "feature": you can pass `argv=NULL` (instead of a pointer to a NULL pointer) with `xor esi,esi`.

(Using `mov reg,0` completely defeats the purpose of the jmp/call/pop trick for avoiding zero bytes.  You might as well just use a normal RIP-relative LEA if zero bytes are allowed.  But if not, you can jump forward over data then use RIP-relative LEA with a negative displacement.)

Comment: First code still works when I run it with xor rsi, rsi instead of moving argv into rsi. Second code now displays nothing and exits but shell still isn't runned.

Comment: @RomanKwaśniewski: So debug it with GDB and strace.  Are you *sure* it doesn't run a shell?  Either way you get a shell prompt, so the difference between working vs. silent exit is not obvious unless you use `strace`.  I don't see how this code could ever return unless you added an `_exit` system call.   And BTW, `xor esi,esi` does zero RSI; that wasn't a mistake in my answer.  No need to introduce a useless REX prefix to make the 64-bit zeroing explicit instead of implicit from writing a 32-bit register.

Comment: How to do this `push 'shsh' / lea rax, [rsp+2]` trick? I tried to do this in different variants and each time received `Illegal instruction (core dumped)` or `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: @RomanKwaśniewski: You just do it to create a zero-terminated `"sh"` string pointed to by RAX.  Then you push a zeroed register and then RAX to create `argv[]` on the stack, and `mov rsi, rsp`.